# Why am I unable to access these partitioned parquet files in Dbeaver, while it works well on Synapse?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse, dbeaver

I try to access some views in my SQL Serverless via Dbeaver.

I have several partitioned parquet files on Azure ADLS, and a Synapse Workspace where I use SQL Serverless to access these data.

Everything work well on Synapse.

[image]

But on DBeaver, the same query won't work

[image]

¿Does anyone know why this happen?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using Synapse studio, you are using an Azure AD user, with access to the underline storage. When you are connecting with dbeaver, you probably use an SQL user, and you need to grant it access to the storage files.

Please see this [link](https://www.madeiradata.com/post/external-tables-with-sql-user) for detailed steps to enable access for SQL users.

Comment: I'll test it and let you know